# post bootstrap-slider input data value using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-slider

I add **multiple** bootstrap-slider in my `PHP` page like this :

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="sliderMaster slider-horizontal" id="sl2" name="q2" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="100" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="50" value="50" data-slider-orientation="horizontal" data-slider-selection="after" data-slider-tooltip="show">
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
  $('#sl2').slider({
        formater: function(value) {
          return 'Current value: '+value;
        }
  }).on('slideStop', function(ev){
     $(this).val($(this).data('slider').getValue());
  });
});
```

I need to change value when i slide ranger and post data input `value` with `PHP` `$_POST` *form submit*. But in action `input value` not change and i see default `value`. how do fix this and post data input value ?!

DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/Sambora/D7Ctg/148/

Comment: You have to use [jQuery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to send the new value to PHP.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using multiple sliders then give input names like `name='q[]'` for all input slider elements

and access this input data in PHP POST like `$_POST['q[0]'], $_POST['q[1]'],` .... like this

and your modified code like this

```
<form id="formSlider" type="POST" action="abc.php">
    <input type="text" class="sliderMaster slider-horizontal sl2" name="q[]" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="100" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="50" value="50" data-slider-orientation="horizontal" data-slider-selection="after" data-slider-tooltip="show">
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <input type="text" class="sliderMaster slider-horizontal sl2" name="q[]" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="100" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="50" value="50" data-slider-orientation="horizontal" data-slider-selection="after" data-slider-tooltip="show">
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <input type="text" class="sliderMaster slider-horizontal sl2" name="q[]" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="100" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="50" value="50" data-slider-orientation="horizontal" data-slider-selection="after" data-slider-tooltip="show">
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <input type="text" class="sliderMaster slider-horizontal sl2" name="q[]" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="100" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="50" value="50" data-slider-orientation="horizontal" data-slider-selection="after" data-slider-tooltip="show">
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <input type='submit' value='Submit' />
</form>
```

and script

```
$( "#formSlider" ).submit(function( event ) { 
    var post_data = $("#formSlider").serialize();
    alert(post_data); 
});

$(function () {
    $('.sl2').slider({
        formater: function (value) {
            return 'Current value: ' + value;
        }
    }).on('slideStop', function (ev) {
        $(this).val($(this).data('slider').getValue());
    });
});
```

**Note:** added submit handler in script just to watch the results in alert box you can remove it.

Hope it works for you :)

Comment: I have Multiple slider and another fields so need to send with `<form></form>` submit. `(jQuery Or Normal Post using php)`